# Switch foundation 6 tabs automatically

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation 6 in my recent project, and there is a slider with tabs underneath it, so I decided to use built in foundation 6 tabs and switch them automatically via JavaScript, the problem is I can't find function to call it on the next tab in `setInterval` function, like Bootstrap's `show("tab")` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have came up with the solution by adding the `is-active` class to the next tab and tab panel

```
function tabSwitch() {
    var tabs = $("ul.tabs");
    var tab_content = $(".tabs-content");
    var currentTab = tabs.find(".is-active");
    var currentPanel = tab_content.find(".is-active");

    currentTab.removeClass('is-active').find("[aria-selected]").attr('aria-selected', false);

    if (currentTab.next('li').length !== 0) {
        currentTab.next("li").addClass('is-active').find("[aria-selected]").attr('aria-selected', true);
    } else {
        tabs.find("li:first").addClass('is-active').find("[aria-selected]").attr('aria-selected', true);
    }

    if (currentPanel.next('.tabs-panel').length !== 0) {
        currentPanel.removeClass("is-active").next(".tabs-panel").addClass("is-active");
    } else {
        currentPanel.removeClass("is-active");
        tab_content.find(".tabs-panel:first").addClass("is-active");
    }
}

var saleTimer = setInterval(tabSwitch, 5000);

$("ul.tabs").find(".is-active").on("click", function () {
    clearInterval(saleTimer);
    saleTimer = setInterval(tabRotate, 5000);
});
```